# If $X$ is a set and $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology on $X$, is the following statement true

Tags: general-topology

> If $X$ is a set and $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology on $X$, is the following statement true:
>
> - $\{X\} \in \mathcal T$?

I know that since $\mathcal T$ is a topology we know that $X \in \mathcal T$. However, what is meant by $\{X\} \in \mathcal T$? Does it mean "The set that contains $X$ is in contained in $\mathcal T$? Because that to me sounds false?

I would think that the correct version of the statement is $\{ X \} \subseteq\mathcal T$?

Comment: Yes, $\{X\}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$ is true, because it's the same as saying $X\in\mathcal{T}$, which is true for *every* topology on $X$. On the other hand $\{X\}\in\mathcal{T}$ implies $\{X\}\subseteq X$, which in turn means $X\in X$, which is false under the standard ZFC axioms of set theory.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking on this is exactly right.  $\{X\}$ is the set whose only member is $X$.  Since $\{X\}$ is not a subset of $X$, it can never be an element in a topology on $X$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! :). I appreciate it. Is my final edit of what I think the correct statement might be, true?

Comment: It is true that $\{X\}\subseteq\mathcal T$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space such that $\lbrace x \rbrace \in \mathcal{T} \subset P(X)$ $\forall x \in X$, then $\mathcal{T}=P(X)$, since $\forall Y \in P(X)$ we have $Y:=\bigcup_{y \in Y} \lbrace y \rbrace \in \mathcal{T}$, and also $P(X) \subset \mathcal{T}$, i.e. also $\lbrace X \rbrace \subset P(X)=\mathcal{T}$.